# Scan input for numbers and add thousands separators

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

Given ASCII-encoded text input of any size, detect numbers between -1,000,000,000,000,000,000 and 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 exclusive and rewrite them with thousands separators. Use commas only and ignore leading zeroes. Leave the rest of the input unchanged.

## Test cases

| Input | Output | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `123` | `123` |  |
| `1234` | `1,234` |  |
| `-12345` | `-12,345` |  |
| `x12345y` | `x12,345y` | ignore surrounding characters |
| `1234 xyz 56789` | `1,234 xyz 56,789` |  |
| `1234,56789` | `1,234,56,789` | 1,234 and 56,789 are separate numbers |
| `0001234` | `0001,234` | zeroes are not part of the number |
| `10000000` | `10,000,000` | only leading zeroes are ignored |
| `1234567891234567890` | `1234567891234567890` | 1,234,567,891,234,567,890 is outside the range |
| `0123456789123456789` | `0123,456,789,123,456,789` |  |

---

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I think handling the test cases `0001234` and `1234567891234567890` as exceptions makes this a less attractive challenge.

Comment: Suggested test case: `123456789000123456789` -> `123456789000123456789` (solutions might conceivably parse it by mistake as `123456789` plus `000123456789`)

Comment: May input contain dots? May input already contain commas? What should the program do for these situations?

Comment: @tsh There is a test case with a comma in the input.

Comment: Suggested test case: `0123456789123456789` -> `0123,456,789,123,456,789` (18 digits if the leading zero is disgarded). Some entries fail on this one.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>58</s> 50 bytes

```perl
s%[1-9]\d*%$&<1E18?$&=~s/.\K(?=(...)+$)/,/gr:$&%ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YNdpQ1zI2JkVLVUXNxtDV0MJeRc22rlhfL8Zbw95WQ09PT1NbRVNfRz@9yEpFTTU99f9/QyNjLiA24dIFkaZcFWCqEiymUFFZpWBqZm5hCebqQJgGBgZgDYYGEACWA0sZwFlIYgiAEPuXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv24BAA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

*-3 thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/0|\d+/g,s=>s[18]?s:s.replace(/.(?=(...)+$)/g,"$&,"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHtCoIwFIb/dxXjELHRac4@LTAvpPohZlFIRovQ6N5tUyvZ1mAw9rwPvDs7x49YJrfT9T665Pu0OoSVDNeS39JrFicp9cRrux96R9S3Gz/YRXLVoZxGIeWcs2GfqRD0BwiMVUl@kXmW8iw/0gMFfzwBYizGCPE8olDPTk/hTxoVM/MjLczAlVcIFTONojZKcBhFY5SuUqQon2Q2XwRLsEq1DBV0qdjRTBXdmhDCmkSraeSahC@aBY7JCVRAb1e9ut33IOD3OSayWtqZj60RTpvHYedcvQE)

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                   // s = input string
s.replace(             // replace in s:
  /0|\d+/g,            //   we define a number as either a single zero
                       //   or a sequence of digits without leading zeros
  s =>                 //   for each such number s,
  s[18] ?              //   if it's longer than 18 characters:
    s                  //     leave it unchanged
  :                    //   else:
    s.replace(         //     replace in s:
      /.(?=(...)+$)/g, //       each digit followed by one or several groups of
                       //       3 digits covering exactly the end of the string
      "$&,"            //       with the same digit followed by a comma
    )                  //     end of replace()
)                      // end of replace()
```

Comment: maybe change the regex into `/0|\d+/g`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>88</s> 85 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [movatica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86751).*

```python
lambda s:re.sub('[1-9]\d*',lambda n:len(a:=n[0])<19and f'{int(a):,}'or a,s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NDoMgEITvPsXegAYbqP1RUp9EPWDU1ETRAE20TZ@diq3OZb7d2U1mnO1jUFE8atekuetkX1YSjND10TxLjDIeJkVeHRD9R0p0tcJSpCpjBbnzRKoKGvRulcWSCPpBgwZJDQnafhy0BV07WxtrIIUM8VOEKHg7ew89XDxNK81bCNP8gsv1Fifbhu4TY2z75@yn7Wi92YGhIgiapY6FVsFaQgSwaNS@bYMtIe4L)

Right tool for the job.

### More regex-y solution, <s>93</s> 92 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121). Another one bytes the dust thanks to [movatica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86751).*

```python
lambda s:re.sub('(^0*|\D0*)([1-9]\d{,17})(?!\d)',lambda n:n[1]+f'{int(n[2]):,}',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NDoIwEITvPMV6aovVtCL@NDFefAvABAKNJFpIWxNRefZqUZjLfLs7m0zb2UujIicPqbvmt6LMwQhdLc29wAifWfhOTywkOOGLfZaWL8q3PcHHWVoSRP8PSqiEZ3OJXrWyWCWrjAjaI2pIUN/aRlvQlbOVsQYOkCC@ihAFb2vvCw@xp8dA3XiER/eEeLPd7ccNnSbG2PjP2U9jaMhMwFAWBLLRYKFWMJQQAXzVal9WYkuI@wA)

Tries to check for the length restriction within the regex, but I'm not very good at regex so it could probably be better. :P

Comment: Your second solution matches part of longer numbers when they contain a 0 (numbers like `1111111111111111111011111111111`). I think it can be fixed with `(^0*|\D0*)` instead of `(^|\D|0)`.

Comment: And a negative lookahead will save a bit: `(?=\D|$)` -> `(?!\d)`

Comment: You can omit the `0` as start of a range: `\d{0,17} == \d{,17}`

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY7NDoMgEITvPsXegAYbqP1RUp9EPWDU1ETRAE20TZ@diq3OZb7d2U1mnO1jUFE8atekuetkX1YSjND10TxLjDIeJkVeHRD9R0p0tcJSpCpjBbnzRKoKGvRulcWSCPpBgwZJDQnafhy0BV07WxtrIIUM8VOEKHg7ew89XDxNK81bCNP8gsv1Fifbhu4TY2z75@yn7Wi92YGhIgiapY6FVsFaQgSwaNS@bYMtIe4L "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") for the first solution by introducing the walruss operator

Comment: [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU7BDoIwFLvzFS9eBmaYIaKwyJfADhAgksBYtpmAhG9HB45e2r72JRWTfg08jIVcmzRfu6IvqwIUlfVFvUsXZYGfsLw6I/yPOG3Q3HLt8owwj84nfMpoV/PdP4OELQvCynPaXgxSg6xXXSutIIUMBdcQYTB0M@wbERk1bmqyIYzTB6L7I07sBR@OEGL/A7LDlrbOIQhijtMMEjS0HLYR1IEfhDT7G1d73voF "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") using a format trick like in [Jitses Python 3 post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271770/86751)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 52 bytes

```
r`(?<=[1-9]0*)\d{3}(?(?=\d)\G|(?<![1-9]\d{18,}))
,$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/KEHD3sY22lDXMtZASzMmpdq4VsNew942JkUzxr0GKKcIlgNKGFro1GpqcumoqP3/b2hkzAXEJly6INKUqwJMVYLFFCoqqxRMzcwtLMFcHQjTwMAArMHQAALAcmApOMMAAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
r`
```

Use right-to-left matching. In particular, this starts matching from the end of the string and works back to the start. This is important for the `\G` reference, which effectively now matches the start of the next match rather than the end of the previous match.

```
(?<=[1-9]0*)
```

Each set of three digits must be preceded by at least one nonzero digit.

```
\d{3}
```

Match three digits.

```
(?(?=\d)\G|(?<![1-9]\d{18,}))
```

If the next character is also a digit, then the matches need to be contiguous, otherwise there must not be a non-zero digit at least 18 digits away.

```
,$&
```

Precede the three digits with a comma.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 90 bytes

Thanks for @movatica for code improvement.

In golfed version, `scala.util.matching.Regex` is imported implicitly.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVCxTsMwEBVrvuJkgeSgJEoohbaQSB2RCgtioc3gJk4b5DiV7ULaKl_CUgZY-CL4GhKbVEJ48Hv37t35zq8fMiGM9D6nyOXlCxEcxd9HYTl_oomCW5Jz2FkAKc2gaAJMxEKOYCwE2Uzvlcj5IrZH8MBzBaF2AjwTBopKJRtlkkuFUXDWQw60cN6i25J-yyrNNl0Sqs0W-heXg2GnOIfI9_2uPvDN6UzacyBa9v_ryNbT6UuP52WloCRZ4mb0CFbNLopxLOiKkYTerYs5FRIr227rasuyzGZ_8yPA5hfCyKDdLP2-Vpk7-HqUYYSmgTuMZ7P0FHnC-60dM3bDsXSKMNq1Lauw8AqikiVNr_IMV57Mt_Q6GNoZOt5VnionJV_UJ06KKJMUqto2L7zVBvd7gz8)

```scala
s=>"[1-9]\\d*".r.replaceAllIn(s,m=>{val x=m.matched;if(x.size<19)f"${x.toLong}%,d"else x})
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVLLTsMwEJQ45itWFkgxaqKEUmgrqNQjUuEA4tT24CZOauQ4le1CH-qX9NILXPgjvgbHSR8BX9azs7P2jr39UhHhpPk9RJ7IP4gUaLz7nOvEa_-cActmudRgS_y5ZtzPiI6mTKT-M03pwnHyyRuNNDwSJmDtAMQ0gcwAl8hUdaEvJVkOX7Q0kjHuwqtgGu5tJcA74aCp0spkBkxp12YBUHjVRI0TcH1EXgFbR7yweFkvh8VyBa2b23annm_8yQVBUO8eBuWqy6zqsDkhg_8sshx2bLDD-UkuKYmmrhm8BzPjhObClXTGSUSf5tmESuVqjLGRbApdYUud7oJbWlh0KHfYeGZ869lz0DD0OuPRKL5EvvQrbZ_zB7G3VO3vnBUtWAJuVj4ljX3FVhTuIOxgSND5-kjofJCLdHPRiBFQrigcqGrITflRqv-yq-Iv)

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val tests = List(
      "123",
      "1234",
      "-12345",
      "x12345y",
      "1234 xyz 56789",
      "1234,56789",
      "0001234",
      "10000000",
      "1234567891234567890",
      "0123456789123456789"
    )

    tests.foreach(t => println(replaceNumbers(t)))
  }

  val replaceNumbers: (String => String) = s =>
    "[1-9]\\d*".r.replaceAllIn(
      s,
      m => if (m.matched.size < 19) f"${m.matched.toLong}%,d" else m.matched
    )
}
```

Comment: This seems to fail on `0123456789123456789` -> `0123,456,789,123,456,789`

Comment: @Jitse Yes, you are right. Any correction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about a port of the Python 3 answer: `s=>"[1-9]\\d*".r.replaceAllIn(s,m=>if(m.matched.size<19)f"${m.matched.toLong}%,d"else m.matched)`

Comment: Besides, I'm pretty sure, the import statement needs to be included in the bytecount

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 60 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>s.replace(/0|(\d+)(\d{3})/g,(_,a,b)=>a<1e15?[f(a),b]:_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHrCsIgGIb/dxXiL6Wv6ap1otWFVAzbXBRjRkZsHa59uRoVzkRFeN4HXj4P4iJ0fNofz71cJbJKQ7N1uNDeSR4zEUvC@J2sky41123woGwHJAIBWxouxNyXfrBcpURQ2G5mEa1ilWuVSS9TO5IS7PcHGFmLUoQYQwZ12ukh/pMGw@x8rxYC7MobBIbZRvEySuwwirdRukqhoryiYDSeTHGrVMPAQJcKP5qtglvjnLcm0Wg1ck3C5@@FHZPjYEB9XPVe7T4Pjr@fY6PqCQ)

```javascript
f=s=>                 // Will recurse
s.replace(            // Replace
  /0|(\d+)(\d{3})/g,  // Leading zero treated as a single part
                      // which would also convert to 0
  (_,a,b)=>           // (matched, matched[:-3], matched[-3:]
    a<1e15?           // If matched < 1e18, then a < 1e15
                      // Also 1e15 is smaller than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
                      // so no error would occur 
      [f(a),b]        // matched[-3:] is a group
    :                 // Notice that matched[:-3] also work as a part
      _               // If matched >= 1e18 or matched is undefined
                      // aka. matching a single 0,
)                     // then return as-is.
```

Looks portable to other languages.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 112 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,x=1:s and(s[':'>s>'1':1]or f'{int(s[:(x:=[*map(str.isdigit,s),0].index(0))]):{","[:x<19]}}')+f(s[x:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUzbboMwDH3nK6y@JF4zlKyXgTX6IzQPTEAbqQ0R4SGs6rfTkEqzZPvY5@Lm6TrYXeHGZemrW3P/bRvwIlSKPDS25b5mxE7@xBQjpYcRevYwdop/4oGq@uPeOO6nMTe@NRczCY9C6tzYtgtcImqkx0Zsago/qtTPJ8NtH82BNC59jPNgLAyus1FMGYAb1/QoyWOocZydLUPERX3tstj77HOdhyykNacfhPkPDsfvokyneEMpZTIo@a7EJeofSFjhCw)

Wrong tool for the job (but sans regex)

-15 thanks to [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

Comment: Hah, that's funny. You can use the format specifier `,` to save some bytes.

Comment: @totallyhuman I did not know that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
Ｆ⊞Ｏ⪪Ｓ¹ω¿№ＩΦχ∨υλι⊞υι«⮌⪫⪪⮌⪫υω³…,‹Ｌυ¹⁹≔⟦⟧υι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5Na8MwDD03v0L0JIMLzrpuKz6VQGGj0LIexw4huInB2MEfXbOx3@7ZzhhM8GTpSX5P3dDazrQqxouxgKfghuMobOuNxfOopMdnPQZ/9lbqHgmFOuGDEJAXwMYE7bFpnce9VF5YrBmFo8VAQRGSNmXazJqZkYSDUE7AV7U4JTmPr@IqrBP4YqT@dftHhWJFYZ3QTJ0SzWBGXNIlhYNwDg9C9z5p57O2JAevFjvnZK/x7Z1CyP1slcyr7xjruzVPuOernDf8Vp6pcHCbPmHz8Pi0LS2dS8ZY@VCzOcqsjP4KVsXVVf0A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⊞Ｏ⪪Ｓ¹ω
```

Split the input into characters, append the empty string to the list, then loop over them.

```
¿№ＩΦχ∨υλι
```

Test whether the current character is a digit from `0-9` or `1-9` depending on whether any digits have been collected yet.

```
⊞υι
```

If it is a collectable digit then collect it.

```
«
```

Otherwise:

```
⮌⪫⪪⮌⪫υω³…,‹Ｌυ¹⁹
```

Reverse the digits, regroup them into strings of three characters, join them with commas if there are fewer than 19, and reverse the result.

```
≔⟦⟧υ
```

Clear the list of digits.

```
ι
```

Output the current "non-digit" (could be `0` if we're not collecting digits yet).

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 51 bytes

```
⍜⊜□⍚(⟨◌|/◇⊂↘1♭≡⊂@,⊜□⇌\+=0◿3⇡⟩<19.⧻.)↧\+≠@0⟜∊,+@0⇡10
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2c4oqc4pah4o2aKOKfqOKXjHwv4peH4oqC4oaYMeKZreKJoeKKgkAs4oqc4pah4oeMXCs9MOKXvzPih6Hin6k8MTku4qe7LinihqdcK-KJoEAw4p-c4oiKLCtAMOKHoTEwCgpGICIxMjMiCkYgIjEyMzQiCkYgIi0xMjM0NSIKRiAieDEyMzQ1eSIKRiAiMTIzNCB4eXogNTY3ODkiCkYgIjEyMzQsNTY3ODkiCkYgIjAwMDEyMzQiCkYgIjEwMDAwMDAwIgpGICIxMjM0NTY3ODkxMjM0NTY3ODkwIgo=)

```
⍜⊜□⍚(⟨◌|/◇⊂↘1♭≡⊂@,⊜□⇌\+=0◿3⇡⟩<19.⧻.)↧\+≠@0⟜∊,+@0⇡10
                                             +@0⇡10  # the digits
                                           ∊,        # mask of locations
                                     \+≠@0⟜          # mask of non-leading zeros
                                    ↧                # combine
⍜⊜□⍚(                              )                 # map over mask groups
     ⟨◌|                    ⟩<19.⧻.                  # only process if < 19 digits
                     \+=0◿3⇡                         # mask of triplet groups
                    ⇌                                # reverse
                  ⊜□                                 # split
           ↘1♭≡⊂@,                                   # put comma between each triplet
        /◇⊂                                          # join
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 31 bytes

```
aR`[1-9]\d+`{#a<19?R:Ra<>3J',a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhb7E4MSog11LWNjUrQTqpUTbQwt7YOsghJt7Iy91HUSayGqoIpv6kUrGRgYGBoZmyhUVFYp6JqamVtYGhgogESgbAM4WykWqg0A)

#### Explanation

```lisp
aR`[1-9]\d+`{#a<19?R:Ra<>3J',a}­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
aR                               ; ‎⁡In command-line argument, replace
  `[1-9]\d+`                     ; ‎⁢1-9 followed by more digits
            {                 }  ; ‎⁣with the following callback function:
             #a<19?              ; ‎⁤ If the length of the match is less than 19 digits:
                     Ra          ; ‎⁢⁡  Reverse the match
                       <>3       ; ‎⁢⁢  Group into substrings of length 3
                          J',    ; ‎⁢⁣  Join on comma
                   R:            ; ‎⁢⁤  Reverse back
                             a   ; ‎⁣⁡ Otherwise, return the match unchanged
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

The double-reversal is necessary because `<>` groups from the left; for example, `1234<>3 == [123;4]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `d`, 28 bytes

```
ᵛK¯0Jƒ“ƛ⌊[ᶤ⌊∦ΘİfƛL19<[Ṛ⁻',jṚ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJkIiwiIiwi4bWbS8KvMErGkuKAnMab4oyKW+G2pOKMiuKIps6YxLBmxptMMTk8W+G5muKBuycsauG5miIsIiIsIlwiaiAxMjMgMTIzNCAtMTIzNDUgeDEyMzQ1eSAxMjM0IHh5eiA1Njc4OSAxMjM0LDU2Nzg5IDAwMDEyMzQgMTAwMDAwMDAgMTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzNDU2Nzg5MCAwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzNDU2Nzg5IGhlbGxvd29ybGRcIiIsIjMuNC4yIl0=)

no regex needed

```
ᵛK¯0Jƒ“ƛ⌊[ᶤ⌊∦ΘİfƛL19<[Ṛ⁻',jṚ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁤​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
ᵛK                            # ‎⁡is each character numeric
  ¯0J                         # ‎⁢pairwise differences with a zero appended
     ƒ“                       # ‎⁣split after truthy indices and concatenate sublists
# ‎⁤This splits the string on numbers
       ƛ                      # ‎⁢⁡map over each group
        ⌊[                    # ‎⁢⁢if it is a non-zero number
          ᶤ⌊∦Θİf              # ‎⁢⁣slice at the first non-zero index
                ƛ             # ‎⁢⁤map over each new group
                 L19<[        # ‎⁣⁡if the length is less than 19
                      Ṛ⁻      # ‎⁣⁢reverse and split into triplets
                        ',jṚ  # ‎⁣⁣join by commas and reverse
# ‎⁣⁤d flag concatenates until no sublists remain
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `d`, 25 bytes

```
⁽±Ḋƛ±[⁽⌊Ǒ₍ẎȯƛL19<[Ṙ3ẇ\,jṘ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJkIiwiIiwi4oG9wrHhuIrGm8KxW+KBveKMiseR4oKN4bqOyK/Gm0wxOTxb4bmYM+G6h1xcLGrhuZgiLCIiLCJcImogMTIzIDEyMzQgLTEyMzQ1IHgxMjM0NXkgMTIzNCB4eXogNTY3ODkgMTIzNCw1Njc4OSAwMDAxMjM0IDEwMDAwMDAwIDEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njc4OTAgMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njc4OSBoZWxsb3dvcmxkXCIgIl0=)
vyxal 2 port

Comment: Seems to fail for the test case `0001234`.

Comment: didnt reply, but its fixed @Neil

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.γd}εDdiïDg19‹iR3ô',ýRyγн0Ãì]J
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79zmlNpzW11SMg@vd0k3tHzUsDMzyPjwFnWdw3uDKs9tvrDX4HDz4TWxXv//KykpGRoZcwGxCZcuiDTlqgBTlWAxhYrKKgVTM3MLSzBXB8I0MDAAazA0gACwHFgKzjDgMsAUBFoGAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
.γ                     # Group the characters of the (implicit) input-string by:
  d                    #  Check whether its a non-negative number (aka a digit)
   }ε                  # After the group-by: Map over each group:
     D                 #  Duplicate it
      di               #  If this is a group of digits:
        ï              #   Remove leading 0s by casting it to an integer
         D             #   Duplicate it
          g19‹i        #   If its length is smaller than 19:
               R       #    Reverse it
                3ô     #    Split it into triplets
                  ',ý '#    Join it with "," delimiter
                     R #    Reverse it back
               y       #    Push the current group's string of digits
                γ      #    Split it into equal adjacent groups
                 н     #    Leave only the first group
                  0Ã   #    Leave only the 0s in this group
                    ì  #    Prepend this string (either "" or 0s) to the string
                       #   (implicit) else: use the duplicated integer that's too large
                       #  (implicit) else: use the duplicated non-digit group
    ]                  # Close both the nested if-statements and map
     J                 # Join all groups back together
                       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```